# Find the value of a key from an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array in PHP:

```
Array
(
    [en-CA] => English
    [fr-CA] => Français
    [es-ES] => Español
)
```

I would like to get the language name from the key.

So I made this but it doesn't work:

```
$lang = "en-CA";
$curLang = array_search($lang, $languages);
```

`$curLang` returns me nothing.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you went through docs of http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$languages =   Array
   (
     [en-CA] => English
     [fr-CA] => Français
     [es-ES] => Español
  )

 $lang = "en-CA";
 $curLang = $languages[$lang];
```

Answer (score 0):

> array_search — Searches the array for a given **value** and returns the first corresponding key if successful

You are actually searching for a key, not a value.

So you can just do this to get the value you want.

```
$curLang = $languages[$lang];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can searching for a key, not a value.

```
<?php
$languages = array(

    'en-CA' => 'English',
    'fr-CA' => 'Français',
    'es-ES' => 'Español',
);  

$lang = "en-CA";
if (array_key_exists($lang, $languages)) {
  echo $languages[$lang];
}
?>
```